# MySQL disappeared row

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysql-connector

I created a MySQL RDS instance on AWS and used mysql.connector module to create and insert values into the tables. However, the inserted rows are not present after insertion was successful.

My table schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        task_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        start_time DATETIME,
        end_time DATETIME)
```

My insertion query:

```
f"INSERT INTO t{table_name} (task_name, start_time, end_time) VALUES ('{task_name}', '{start_time}', '{end_time}')"
```

I tried manually adding rows through MySQL Workbench with the exact same query and it works. One interesting thing I noticed was since the `id` column is set to `INCREMENT`, every time I make an insertion through python mysql.connector and then MySQL Workbench, the row that was successfully added had its id incremented by 2, meaning the insertion through python was successful but somehow got removed.

Comment: It sounds like you are not committing the transaction, while MYSQL Workbench probably automatically commits the transaction. After inserting the data, try a `COMMIT` command.

Comment: Try `show variables like 'autocommit';` to verirfy the auto commit setting.

Comment: Can you share the whole snippet with your sql statement?

Comment: `COMMIT` was the issue! Thank you.